# getView sendo chamado diversas vezes

Tags: android, listview

Estou criando um app Android e me deparei com um problema, criei um adapter para preencher os itens da minha tela porém o método getView está sendo chamado diversas vezes quando seleciono o produto assim repetindo os detalhes diversas vezes, quando na verdade deveria ser chamado apenas uma, segue abaixo fragmentos mínimos para uma compreensão do problema.

**XMl onde contém os itens**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/laydadosprodutos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="7dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDetaCodigoProduto"
        style="@style/detaProdutos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDetaDescricao"
        style="@style/detaProdutos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDetaCodigoProduto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDetaCodigoGrupo"
        style="@style/detaProdutos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDetaDescricao" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDetaPreco"
        style="@style/detaProdutos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDetaCodigoGrupo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQtdeDispProd"
        style="@style/detaProdutos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDetaPreco" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProduto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtQtdeDispProd"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtQtdeDispProd"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterDetalheProdutosListView extends BaseAdapter
 {
private LayoutInflater                  mInflater;
private GruposProdutoDetalhesActivity   context;
private String[]                        filepath;
private String                          filename;
private Produto                         produto;
File                                    file;
private String                          caminhoImagem;

public AdapterDetalheProdutosListView(GruposProdutoDetalhesActivity context, String[] fpath, String fname, Produto produto)
{
    this.produto = produto;
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{

    return filepath.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{

    return position;
}
//METODO SENDO CHAMADO MAIS DE UMA VEZ
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Locale brasil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#######0.0000", new DecimalFormatSymbols(brasil));
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    decimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);

    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.itens_produtos_detalhes, null);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetaCodigoProduto)).setText("Código:     " + produto.getCodigo());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetaDescricao)).setText("Descricao:  " + produto.getDescricao());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetaCodigoGrupo)).setText("Grupo:      " + produto.getCodigoGrupo());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetaPreco)).setText("Preço:   R$ " + decimalFormat.format(produto.getPreco()));
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQtdeDispProd)).setText("Estoque: " + produto.getQtdeEstoque());

    for (int i = 0; i < filepath.length; i++)
    {           
        if (filepath[i].endsWith(filename))
        {
            caminhoImagem = filepath[i];
        }
    }

    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageProduto);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(caminhoImagem);       
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);


    return view;
}
```

**Fragmento da minha activity que seta o adapter**

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro, SDCARD Não Encontrado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
    {

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "imagem");
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        listcaminhoImagens = new String[listFile.length];

        listNomeImagens = new String[listFile.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {
            listcaminhoImagens[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();

            listNomeImagens[i] = listFile[i].getName();

            produto.getCodigo().contains(listNomeImagens[i]);

            nomeImagem = listNomeImagens[i];
        }
    }

    adapterDetalheProdutosListView = new AdapterDetalheProdutosListView(this, listcaminhoImagens, nomeImagem, produto);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaDetalheProdutos);

    listView.setAdapter(adapterDetalheProdutosListView);

    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: O método `getView()` é chamado sempre que é necessário apresentar uma nova linha da *ListView* por isso é natural que seja chamado várias vezes.

Comment: @ramaral o problema é que eu só quero exibir os detalhes dos produtos uma vez

Comment: A sua listview está como wrap_content? Se estiver, tenta mudar para fill_parent ou match_content

Eu achei isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186004/yet-another-getview-called-multiple-times#answer-11187397

Comment: Não estou a perceber. O que é que a sua lista tem? Se quer que o detalhe do produto só apareça quando selecciona um item da lista então o detalhe não pode ser preenchido no `getView` nem fazer parte do xml dos itens.

Comment: @ramaral a lista só tem o caminho das imagens dentro do SDCARD, analisando meu design acho que estou fazendo errado a forma de carregar meus dados